# GeoNetwork 4.2.8 and Azure Kubernetes Service catalogue-data not persisting

Tags: java, geonetwork

I am trying to run GeoNetwork 4.2.8 on Azure Kubernetes Service but am experiencing an issue with the catalogue-data not being persisted when the pod is restarted.
In Kubernetes I have created a persistent volume that is set to retain the volume.

In the GeoNetwork AKS deployment I have set the environment variables:

```
env:
- name: DATA_DIR
  value: /catalogue-data
```

The Java options look like this:

```
- name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: |
                -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.LEVEL=OFF -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms512M -Xss512M -Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dgeonetwork.resources.dir=/catalogue-data/resources -Dgeonetwork.data.dir=/catalogue-data -Dgeonetwork.codeList.dir=/var/lib/jetty/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/config/codelist -Dgeonetwork.schema.dir=/var/lib/jetty/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/config/schema_plugins
```

As I understand it that should be it based on reading the geonetwork documentation: https://hub.docker.com/_/geonetwork/
However every time the pod restarts the file structure within catalogue-data is recreated.
It appears geonetwork is formatting the volume and recreating the files structure each time.
I have created other persistent volumes and mounted them on the geonetwork container and they are not impacted by restarts.

What is wrong? Obviously I want to avoid any data loss here but being quite new to GeoNetwork I am not entirely sure what the impact of losing the catalogue-data directory is. Is it recreated based on data in the database? Or should it absolutely be persisted?

Kubernetes details:
Azure Kubernetes service
Version: 1.28.5
Storage type: Azure disk

Storage class:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azuredisk-csi-waitforfirstconsumer
provisioner: disk.csi.azure.com
parameters:
  skuname: StandardSSD_LRS
allowVolumeExpansion: true
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Persistent volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: disk.csi.azure.com
  name: {{ .Values.pv.geoCataloguePvName }}
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: {{ .Values.pv.geoCataloguePvSize }}
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: azuredisk-csi-waitforfirstconsumer
  csi:
    driver: disk.csi.azure.com
    volumeHandle: {{ .Values.pv.geoCataloguePvDiskResourceId }}
    volumeAttributes:
      fsType: ext4
```

Persistent Volume Claim

```
{{- $global := .Values.global | default dict }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.pvc.geoCataloguePvcName }}
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: {{ .Values.pvc.geoCataloguePvcSize }}
  volumeName: {{ .Values.pv.geoCataloguePvName }}
  storageClassName: azuredisk-csi-waitforfirstconsumer
```

Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "geonetwork.fullname" . }}
  annotations:
    geonetwork.version: {{ .Chart.Version }}
  labels:
{{ include "geonetwork.labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      geonetwork/app: {{ include "geonetwork.name" . }}
      geonetwork/siteName: {{ .Release.Name }}
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        geonetwork/app: {{ include "geonetwork.name" . }}
        geonetwork/siteName: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
    {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 999
        runAsGroup: 999
        fsGroup: 999
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
            - name: DATA_DIR
              value: /catalogue-data
            - name: ES_HOST
              value: {{ .Values.elasticsearch.host }}
            - name: ES_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.elasticsearch.port }}"
            - name: ES_PROTOCOL
              value: {{ .Values.elasticsearch.protocol }}
            - name: GEONETWORK_DB_HOST
              value: {{ .Values.postgres.host }}
            - name: GEONETWORK_DB_NAME
              value: {{ .Values.postgres.dbname }}
            - name: GEONETWORK_DB_PASSWORD
              value: {{ .Values.postgres.password }}
            - name: GEONETWORK_DB_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.postgres.port }}"
            - name: GEONETWORK_DB_TYPE
              value: {{ .Values.db_type }}
            - name: GEONETWORK_DB_USERNAME
              value: {{ .Values.postgres.dbuser }}
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: |
                -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.LEVEL=OFF -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms512M -Xss512M -Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dgeonetwork.resources.dir=/catalogue-data/resources -Dgeonetwork.data.dir=/catalogue-data -Dgeonetwork.codeList.dir=/var/lib/jetty/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/config/codelist -Dgeonetwork.schema.dir=/var/lib/jetty/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/config/schema_plugins
          ports:
            - name: tcp
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /catalogue-data
              name: geonetwork
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /metadata-import
              name: geonetwork-metafileshare
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: geonetwork
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: {{ .Values.pvc.geoCataloguePvcName }}
        - name: geonetwork-metafileshare
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: {{ .Values.pvc.geoMetaDataFileShareName }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

I do see this error in the pod when it first starts:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age   From                     Message
  ----     ------                  ----  ----                     -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling        56s   default-scheduler        0/1 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
  Warning  FailedScheduling        54s   default-scheduler        0/1 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
  Normal   Scheduled               47s   default-scheduler        Successfully assigned geonetwork/geonetwork-758f99fd88-g8l59 to aks-nodepool1-12489523-vmss000001
  Normal   Pulled                  46s   kubelet                  Container image "jingking/geonetwork-hnap:4.2.8" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                 45s   kubelet                  Created container geonetwork-k8s
  Normal   Started                 45s   kubelet                  Started container geonetwork-k8s
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  34s   attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "geonetwork-azuredisk-pv"
```

Comment: In the Admin console --> Information and status, check the actual paths GN is using jus to verify that all is in the place you want it. Also don't forget to associate the volume to the container and mount it in the right path.

Comment: It says '/catalogue-data' in the admin console. I have a feeling the container is starting up before the mount has happened possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoNetwork should not format the 'catalogue-data' folder after a restart. You may want to check your mountPath and Storage Class definition.

In your case, you defined two "volumeMounts". The second section will overwrite the first one. So your "/catalogue-data" is always a local drive.

```
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /catalogue-data
          name: geonetwork
      #### volumeMounts: ### This line should be removed. 
        - mountPath: /metadata-import
          name: geonetwork-metafileshare
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have added the aks manifests.